# Classe de template, incluir header e footer

Tags: php, classes, template

Olá, já havia postado aqui há algum tempo sobre minha classe de templates, porém resolvi da uma modificada, por que toda vez que quero editar um menu por exemplo, tenho que editar em todos meus arquivos.

Está é a minha classe

```
class Template {

    private $_template;

    private $_assign = array();

    public function set($file) {
        $path = './templates/' . DEFAULT_THEME . '/header.tpl.php';
        $path = './templates/' . DEFAULT_THEME . '/' . $file . '.tpl.php';
        $path = './templates/' . DEFAULT_THEME . '/footer.tpl.php';

        if (!empty($path)) {
            if (file_exists($path)) {
                $this->_template = file_get_contents($header);
                $this->_template = file_get_contents($path);
                $this->_template = file_get_contents($footer);
            } else {
                die("Template error: file not found in: {$path}.");
            }
        }
    }

    public function assign($string_search, $string_replace) {
        if (!empty($string_search)) {
            $this->_assign[strtoupper($string_search)] = $string_replace;
        }
    }

    public function display() {
        if (count($this->_assign) > 0) {
            foreach ($this->_assign as $key => $value) {
                $this->_template = str_replace('{' . $key . '}', $value, $this->_template);
            }
        }

        return $this->_template;
    }
}
```

E uso assim:

```
<?php

require './includes/configs/Configs.php';
require './includes/autoload/autoload.php';

$template = new Template();

$template->set('home');

$template->assign('home', 'this is home');

echo $template->display();
```

Repare que estou tentando incluir meu header e meu footer na classe template:

```
public function set($file) {
    $path = './templates/' . DEFAULT_THEME . '/header.tpl.php';
    $path = './templates/' . DEFAULT_THEME . '/' . $file . '.tpl.php';
    $path = './templates/' . DEFAULT_THEME . '/footer.tpl.php';

    if (!empty($path)) {
        if (file_exists($path)) {
            $this->_template = file_get_contents($header);
            $this->_template = file_get_contents($path);
            $this->_template = file_get_contents($footer);
        } else {
            die("Template error: file not found in: {$path}.");
        }
    }
}
```

Porém ele adiciona sempre o ultimo que é meu footer, existe alguma maneira de criar uma função ou adicionar sem ter que usar o `require`? Por que quando tento usar o `require` ele não troca minhas strings `str_replace()`;

Bom tentei explicar, aguardo respostas.

Comment: Não entendi o Downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Esse trecho:**

```
public function set($file) {
    $path = './templates/' . DEFAULT_THEME . '/header.tpl.php';
    $path = './templates/' . DEFAULT_THEME . '/' . $file . '.tpl.php';
    $path = './templates/' . DEFAULT_THEME . '/footer.tpl.php';

    if (!empty($path)) {
        if (file_exists($path)) {
            $this->_template = file_get_contents($header);
            $this->_template = file_get_contents($path);
            $this->_template = file_get_contents($footer);
        } else {
            die("Template error: file not found in: {$path}.");
        }
    }
}
```

**faça assim**

```
public function set($file) {

    $this->_template = '';

    $path = './templates/' . DEFAULT_THEME . '/header.tpl.php';

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        $this->_template .= file_get_contents($path);
    } else {
        die("Template error: file not found in: {$path}.");
    }

    $path = './templates/' . DEFAULT_THEME . '/' . $file . '.tpl.php';

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        $this->_template .= file_get_contents($path);
    } else {
        die("Template error: file not found in: {$path}.");
    }

    $path = './templates/' . DEFAULT_THEME . '/footer.tpl.php';

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        $this->_template .= file_get_contents($path);
    } else {
        die("Template error: file not found in: {$path}.");
    }

}
```

Caso queira controlar opções de incluir ou não o header e footer, pode fazer algo assim

```
public function set($file, $header = true, $footer = true) {

    $this->_template = '';

    if (!empty($header)) {
        $path = './templates/' . DEFAULT_THEME . '/header.tpl.php';
        if (file_exists($path)) {
            $this->_template .= file_get_contents($path);
        } else {
            die("Template error: file not found in: {$path}.");
        }
    }

    $path = './templates/' . DEFAULT_THEME . '/' . $file . '.tpl.php';
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        $this->_template .= file_get_contents($path);
    } else {
        die("Template error: file not found in: {$path}.");
    }

    if (!empty($footer)) {
        $path = './templates/' . DEFAULT_THEME . '/footer.tpl.php';
        if (file_exists($path)) {
            $this->_template .= file_get_contents($path);
        } else {
            die("Template error: file not found in: {$path}.");
        }
    }

}
```

Para usar, apenas atribua os parâmetros no momento que instancia a class Template

```
$template = new Template();

// Exemplos
// NÃO inclui o header e  INCLUI o footer:
$template->set('home', false, true);
// também pode chamar assim:
$template->set('home', false);

// NÃO inclui o header e o footer:
$template->set('home', false, false);

// INCLUI o header e NÃO inclui o footer:
$template->set('home', true, false);

// Inclui ambos:
$template->set('home');
// também pode chamar assim:
$template->set('home', true, true);
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu comentário, funcionou da mesma forma que eu tinha feito... está pegando sempre o ultimo que é meu footer.

Comment: Ah, desculpe, esqueci de concatenar. Corrigi a resposta.

Comment: Opa functionou, agora todos os meus templates são obrigados a conter um header e um footer. Vou marcar como resolvido, obrigado, mas assim não querendo folgar em você, você teria uma lógica de como criar uma função pra fazer isso? por exemplo se eu querer separar meu Sidebar do layout e precisar incluir apenas incluo usando a função. Obs: A recompensa só pode ser dada em 22 horas :/

Comment: Imaginei que fosse perguntar isso referente ao header e footer. Há diversas formas de resolver. Vou mostrar um jeito que possibilite implementar sem modificar muito o que já possui.

Comment: Opa, perfeito! vou guardar em um array, assim vou poder incluir outras coisas alem de header e footer, vamos ver se minha lógica irá funcionar... Por exemplo, dividir o layout em partes, sendo eles os arquivos `header.tpl.php`, `menu.tpl.php`, `footer.tpl.php` e etc toda vez que tiver partes adicionais é só ativar no array...